# Why does WCF Restrict us to Only Open a Named Pipe Once per Machine?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, named-pipes

What is the reason for opening a named pipe only once per machine? .I mean what is the reason behind this restriction?

Comment: Please provide a code example which illustrates this.

Comment: you really think your original title is better than my change? Really?

Comment: Please could you explain what restriction you are talking about? I don't think there is one, but perhaps I haven't understood what you are referring to. Since you have tagged the question with ASP.NET and WCF, presumably you have a scenario you could describe, to illustrate what you are asking.

Comment: The title of a question should represent a one line summary of the question you are asking.  It should not be a combination of keywords relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Greg Sansom: I'm not sure the edit (yours?) to the title has helped dispel the uncertainty as to what restriction is being referred to. @Amutha: Did you mean why doesn't WCF let you open two NetNamedPipeBinding services on the same machine both having endpoints with the same service Uri? (Why would you expect it to?)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it makes sense that only one listener can be open on a single named pipe. Allowing two instances of the pipe to be open would create a range of issues, to start with:

1. When we send a message to the service, how do we know which listener is going to accept our message?
2. Do we really need the overhead of avoiding race conditions when two listeners are trying to receive the same message?
3. Would we expect each listener to receive the message, or just one?

Keep in mind that allowing two listeners on the same named pipe would allow two completely different services to receive the same messages.  There is simply no reason to allow this to happen.

**Update** 
[Chris Dickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502194/chris-dickson) points out that allowing two listeners on the same pipe creates a security issue known as a [squatting attack](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2010/11/03/subverting-a-wcf-service-s-named-pipe-endpoint.aspx), where a fraudulent host can receive requests and steal the identity of the caller.  This is a ramification of point 1 above.

Comment: For those of us without telepathy, care to elaborate on "a range of problems"?

Comment: Thank you. Now it's a more than a half a step above answering with "because". ;-) Also, would like to mention that [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28VS.85%29.aspx) can offer [cross-process communication on the same computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226493.aspx), but they can also provide [interprocess communication locally or over a network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx)

Comment: It isn't true in general that "only one listener can be open on a single named pipe". The operating system does not constrain named pipe usage in this way - unless you explicitly ask it to when calling CreateNamedPipe. This is the root of a common security issue with Named Pipes known as a "Squatting Attack". If this question is about WCF NetNamedPipeBinding - it isn't clear - then WCF does now (from .NET 4) correctly constrain to one listener only. In .NET 3.5 and prior it did not and was vulnerable to squatting. See http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi for details.

Comment: If there are two listeners on the same named pipe, they do not see the same messages: when a client connects to the pipe, a new pipe instance is created, and the server end of the pipe instance will be held by one of the listeners only. The other listener will remain blocked in ConnectNamedPipe. I believe the OS chooses the server for each pipe instance in a round robin fashion, but I don't think this is documented.